# How to print out all types of properties of a type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I would like to print out all types of properties of a type in TypeScript. For example, I want to log what properties `AddressWithUnit` has and the types of properties. In the code below, it can be simple to check it manually. However, if a type is combined with multiple types, it can be complicated to check it manually.

```
type BasicAddress = {
  name?: string;
  street: string;
  city: string;
  country: string;
  postalCode: string;
}

interface AddressWithUnit extends BasicAddress {
  unit: string;
}
```

Comment: Interfaces (and the rest of the type system) does not exist at runtime. You cannot do a dynamic lookup at run-time for a compile-time construct.

Comment: as @VLAZ said, this is not possible. You could create a an abstract class that mirrors your type alias however if you need to reference types at run time.

Comment: How would I check it in compile time then? As long as I can check the types, it would be good for me.

Answer (score -1):

> How would I check it in compile time then? As long as I can check the types, it would be good for me.

(Answering keeping this comment of yours in mind)

I'm not sure what is your exact requirement here, but let's assume you want to ensure all values are of type `string` or `number` or `undefined`. So you can do something like this...

```
type BasicAddress = {
  name?: string;
  street: string;
  city: string;
  country: string;
  postalCode: string;
}

interface AddressWithUnit extends BasicAddress {
  unit: string;
}
type TestAddressWithUnit = TestTrue<
  Value<AddressWithUnit> extends string | number | undefined
    ? true
    : false
>;

type Value<T> = T[keyof T]
type TestTrue<T extends true> = T;
```

Now if you mistakenly make `unit` a `boolean` in the definition of `AddressWithUnit` the code won't compile and you'll get an error at `TestAddressWithUnit` like [so](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwJYGMCCATDAnCCFQC8UA3gFBRQB2cAthAPwBcUCw2SVA5gNwWvsIEYCzYdufSiiShR7Tr34oA9gFcq7EHPGLKYZWzgAbAMLKMEbQr4BfMmU7AI2AGZwU0TDjwIA6jIALAFUqGSgIAA8nKgwCeGR0LFx8Un51GRYAI2VlIwg4KlsyUEgoABU8YC9kv0CQsOIKtjLsVQgAHn4ANWM29uqff2Bg0OAAPnCoiBiCMQUoAB9qVVpM50WodQsXTggMfkoGKHY2g6gWNyMECDIxvmLwaB6jPrKJxoBtAGsIEGUXcoAXQepSawBar0m0Vix1aEHe5R4QA)

Now someone like me can even do meta programming, I can write code that gives me [error in natural language](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFKAjAhgJwC4oBnYfASwDsBzTHXAL2KoFcBbbCfegC137FUAX3oAbOGOLYEYiLirpR6UJCgAVCGXhwAErhIBBMWIDK5ajRLIohgHSay6-KwgAeAMK8IAYwDWAGq4Yq5uOgA0pBa0AHwx6Crg0F6+gcGh6pEAqjHI9KhQANoA0lDUUH4QIHAAZhoAusTqJfVQEAAewBBUACbWWVAA-FBUEABu3FDEpcKFldV16q0dXb3W1DWTxfRYwy1tnd19RaMT+K07WFfD5K6XV1NQAAYAovj4cERQxVXWACSoeyGEgkbjATTsMBiXDAXDYORuUx2DxwdjsAxuYpxYRQfgTKCsUbtSA+Lo9KBjdIQJ6XFjjbgJKi4dhaMC4HzQAYYLAdMCfYBQVTQACSJCyVAowDc6lyKEKWTsAAU4GBID1pTFloc1id6echoKXNBiDVgqD6Lz+YKklBlaqIOqZTYFS92j4Qj13JkoAq7Rr4jziVahVBXe7WJ63IZIgAhWW2A6rY4xg2nSbEQwAbgtQfwApDrvI7Kl0agcZshkTR2sKeGlbpZ2zOb5eetaj9TqQl3UcGFVC6+FBpIocCo0qrOsJfiocAA7lQDQAKdpNACUyFyYzgFHJDe4uRW1agy+IG0mivXSE32-Jw0VjzTPGbwZtPb7A6HwBHY87l0X6gnY4pxneclz8NcNwpG8Hz1ddDx1RdF3AsoqE2fAoGFS9rx3ddhmFGDGwSQMW3zV84AAGQoMgNTyB5CiWQDrEKR96nuA1ClYh4sGIQo7D4hUe0o6jfRVNV-WyJUVQ1VjlEtVsmRZEg2Q5KBTDQZ9WxDFE0QxUxInI50HAoqipVMOJaKuAz4OODiDQAIjsqZLis7UbLPdDdFaYZdCch4XKTJi+LsdyoF0SIQoY4YngBci7AAKW3McwqgOzIjsmIcQAMigAEgRBMEIShGE4QRGVhCeXyrkfJR0DkgUFNZdloAM7kDhIttoAS6g3HIyIABFZWcxiii8lLHMIIbrKYkLkqCiLOK44YAKmkaDR84hosBOxgVBPNCuhWF4XcXQMty7b8r2iBIQOkr3AG4QAS6n9+oyiqJoeMhKFobNRDqkZmUalTK1av6Qx2gqrqKw7SvjDwDClb1PssKAAB8Rg4Lh0LR7AKBoagBWx2R5AXNG2BMVGCV6CAamoB0Azal81Dh6jvRyGxltc-oDQA4gsmzYjGegRxwSNccVtuCB43UH6gA)... Apologies for showing off :P

[image: 2]

Comment: "*Now if you mistakenly make unit a boolean the code won't compile and you'll get an error at TestAddressWithUnit*" that's also how TS already works if you just use the type: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwJYGMCCATDAnCCFQC8UA3gFBRQB2cAthAPwBcUCw2SVA5gNwWvsIEYCzYdufSiiShR7Tr34oA9gFcq7EHPGLKYZWzgAbAMLKMEbQr4BfMmU7AI2AGZwU0TDjwIA6jIALAFUqGSgIAA8nKgwCeGR0LFx8Un51GSsJMjsVKjYoZQAjACsiVMoaehYAIjhqgBp+MSERKGrChqUZLTaUTqk1DWwe6ox+qH1DU3NLNohx9Nb2VQhsslz8uCSWL2S-QJCw4iLiniA)

Comment: @VLAZ the user wants to test the type definition itself not the value assigned to it. I've updated the answer with more precise wording a link to a playground to show what error I'm talking about. [Here's the same](https://tsplay.dev/Nd43yN)

Comment: *facepalm* I totally misread the last comment from OP. I thought it said they wanted to check it at runtime.